# Why is CoreData database doubling in size after saving without making any changes?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I have some simple code that saves an image (and some other values) stored in an NSMutableDictionary and the image's thumbnail to CoreData:

```
self.imageInfo.lastSaved = [NSDate date];
self.imageInfo.thumbnail = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self imageThumbnail], JPEGCompressionQuality);

if (!self.imageInfo.details)
{
    self.imageInfo.details = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ImageDetails" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
}

self.imageInfo.details.values = [self imageValues];

NSError *error;
[[self managedObjectContext] save:&error];
```

I have verified the image is 2.1 MB (and the thumbnail is only 11 KB). All other data is just CGFloats or short strings. When I save the first time, everything seems to be OK when I look at the database files in Documents and Directory:

- Image_Producer.sqlite 37 KB
- Image_Producer.sqlite-shm 33 KB
- Image_Producer.sqlite-wal 2.1 KB

However when I save again without changing a thing, I get:

- Image_Producer.sqlite 4.2 KB
- Image_Producer.sqlite-shm 33 KB
- Image_Producer.sqlite-wal 4.3 MB

I have verified that the image size and thumbnail size are staying the same. After five saves I get:

- Image_Producer.sqlite 4.2 MB
- Image_Producer.sqlite-shm 33 KB
- Image_Producer.sqlite-wal 3.3 KB

I don't understand the fluctuation in sizes when I'm not changing a thing. It appears the database has quadrupled in size after the second save, and then goes back to only doubling in size after the first 5 saves. I don't understand what is happening here.

UPDATE: In analyzing the database using sqlite3_analyzer, I see that the payload is the correct size, but yet the size of the sqlite file is exactly double the amount of the payload after 5 saves. Is this standard behavior? Is it creating unnecessary empty space for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to answer on *Why* questions. Did you see any particular problem using Core Data? A singular memory or file size increase as described in your post is neither a failure nor a problem, but if memory or file size would increase continuously for no obvious reason it is a failure. If you are in doubt you could check if Core Data, your App code and SQLite works correctly: open the SQLite file with an SQLite client and enter the `VACUUM` command. Close the SQLite client and check the file size, then repeat the Core Data commands (but don’t add new data) in your app and again enter `VACUUM` through the SQLite client. File size should not have been changed.

Comment: Thanks going to try this out later. CoreData otherwise is working fine so maybe I'm fretting over nothing. I do have two xcdatamodel files and I wonder if this could be causing the problem.